# Serialize Laravel Query Builder

Tags: ajax, url, serialization, laravel, query-builder

I would like to be able to construct a query using laravel, and serialize it into a url string. 
This would allow me to create routes which would unserialize a query builder, run the query, and make a view which displays the database results.

For example, to implement a button which refreshes a list of posts made by kryo:

`http://example.com/ajax/posts.php?name=kryo&order_by=created_at&order_type=desc`

Posts.php would simply be a route which unserializes, validates, and runs the query in the url params, and provides the results to a view.

Perhaps this is not useful in general, but I would personally find it handy specifically for ajax requests. If anyone knows how to implement this as a laravel plugin of some nature, that would be fantastic.

Comment: This would be very useful indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I'll try to give you a basic idea:

In `Laravel` you have to create a `route` to make a request to a function/method, so at first you need to create a `route` which will be listening for the `ajax` request, for example:

```
Route::get('/ajax/posts', array('uses' => 'PostController@index', 'as' => 'showPosts'));
```

Now, create a link in the view which points to this route, to create a link you may try this:

```
$url = to_route('showPosts');
```

If you use something like this:

```
<a class='ajaxPost' href="{{ $url }}?name=kryo&order_by=created_at&order_type=desc">Get Posts</a>
```

It'll create a ink to that route. So, make sure you are able to pass that `$url` to your `JavaScript` or manually you can write the `url` using `/ajax/posts?name=...`. Once you done creating the link then you need to create your `JavaScript` handler for this link (maybe using `click` event) then handle the `click` event from your handler, make `ajax` request, if it's `jQuery` then it could be something like this:

```
$('.ajaxPost').on('clcik', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attar('href');
    $.getJSON(url, function(response){
        $.each(response, function(key, value){
            // loop... you may use $(this) or value
        });
    });
});
```

In your `PostController` controller class, create the index method:

```
class PostController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        $name = Input::get('name');
        $order_by = Input::get('order_by');
        $created_at = Input::get('created_at');
        $order_type = Input::get('order_type');

        $posts = Post::whereName($name)->orderBy($order_by, $order_type)->get();
        if(Request::ajax()) {
            return Response::json($posts);
        }
        else {
            // return a view for non ajax
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to send a rendered view from the server side to your `JavaScript` handler as `HTML` then change the `getJson` to `get` and instead of `return Response::json($posts);` use

```
return View::make('viewname')->with('posts', $posts);
```

In this case make sure that, your view doesn't extends the master `layout`. This may not be what you need but it gives you the idea how you can implement it.

Comment: Any idea how you could make a generic solution that works with all Laravel's query methods? not just whereName and orderBy?